# Should I install npm packages that are dependencies of other installed packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

If I install a npm package `foo` that has a dependency `bar`, then I can just use `bar` in my code. Is there a good reason to still do a `npm install bar`? E.g. when the maintainer of `foo` decides to replace `bar` with something new? Or is that seen as a breaking change in which case I might have to adjust my code anyway?

Comment: Yes, for exactly that reason - if you depend on it directly, add it to your own deps list. This also allows you to use a different version to the one you transitively depend on.

Answer (score 0):

If to use "bar" you are doing npm i "foo" then it means you are directly depending on "foo" instead of "bar", it simply does not make sense anywhere. There are reasons such as,

1. You may be missing out some features in the "bar" package which is not used in "foo"
2. Any error and lag in the "foo" package can directly affect you even when you are not using any of its part
3. Last but not least the one you stated is also 100% correct